# Clonning a repo inside another repo in git

Tags: git, git-clone, repo

I am trying to clone a repo inside another repo. In the inner repo, I want to make some changes according to my need. When i am trying to commit these changes, i am getting an issue:

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
        modified:   infrastructure/accounts/customer/xyz (modified content)
   no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

I want to use the inner repo as a fixed module only for my code.
Please let me know how can i achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add, commit and pushed changes done from your inner repository, you need first to cd (change directory) to your inner repo root folder.

Then you can add/commit/push from that root folder.

Go back one level up, and you can record the new inner repo state (its root tree SHA as a gitlink entry).

Make sure you have added that repository as a [submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) of your parent main project repository.

From that main project, a [`git diff --submodule=diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---submoduleltformatgt) would show the differences from the inner repository.

Comment: I add the repository as a submodule, but on pushing the code (from the inner repo folder), i am not able to see the changes that i made in the inner repo.

Comment: @ChanchalDutta: That's normal. The superproject doesn't record the *files* from the submodule. The superproject records instead the *new commit hash ID* for the new commit that you made *in* the submodule. To make the superproject record that new hash ID, you must first make the commit *in* the submodule (so that it exists and hash a hash ID), then return to the superproject, run `git add` *in* the superproject to update the submodule gitlink, then run `git commit` *in* the superproject to make the new superproject commit.

Comment: The diff from the old superproject commit to the new one will be, or include, the submodule commit hash ID update.

Comment: @ChanchalDutta Try `git diff --submodule=diff` from the main repository. See my edited answer.